# multiple instances of pop window

Tags: php, jquery

I have multiple forms and use a popup window to amend records, i.e. I loop through database records from search criteria to produce a results page. The user has functionality to amend these records via PHP `$_POST`. I have a submit button for each record.

form `onsubmit` runs jQuery code to open a pop up

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=575,height=500,resizeable,scrollbars');
    this.target = 'formpopup';
});
```

This only works for the first instance of `#myform` but all others open in a new tab. I would like them to all show up in a new window. Any ideas please?

Comment: So it opens in a new tab even if you close the original new window you opened. Where does it open a new tab? In that new window or in the original? What browser is this?

Comment: It's appears to be a Chrome issue, only the first instance opens new window, every other opens in tab on original browser. Subsequents open in same tab on the original browswer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have different window names for that to work.  You are only using one window named 'formpopup', so if you wanted a new window to open, it would need a different name, otherwise it will use the current window named 'formpopup' and just open a new tab in that window.

Comment: I would't mind it using same window, but they always open in new tab. I'm resigned to this now and will work around it (IE opens in mulitple windows).